# General developer tools question closed as a duplicate of Chrome Developer Tools question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

[How do you determine what is overriding your style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689619/how-do-you-determine-what-is-overriding-your-style)

The recent question that is closed is more general and has an answer for Firefox Developer Tools from me. I would add my answer also to the older question, but it doesn't fit there.

What is the duplicate handling policy with more general vs older questions?

Comment: Browser developer tools vary widely. A general developer tools question would be too broad.